# php get image name and add to database?

Tags: php, database, image, forms, upload

Hi I'm trying to add my image name to my database, I have a page that adds a file to my server in a folder called uploads but I then want to be able to on creation of a news article, get the image name that I've uploaded and add that to the relevant article in a variable called $Image_Name so I can show the relevant image to the article.

is there some code I can add to my form to search browse the image and add the name to a field then when I do my insert query on the following page just get that value like I do for all my text fields.

Any help would be great as I still very new to php and mysql.

thanks.

Comment: suggestion http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
$image = $_FILES["file"]["name"];                                               
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../upload/$image");                                             
$query = "INSERT INTO images VALUES('','$image')";
```